# How do I redirect http to https

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to redirect http to https. 
I tried this one,but I have one problem, I have to redirect to another page. 
The request.url gives the current page, whereas I need to redirect to another page. 
How do I do that.

```
if(!Request.IsSecureConnection)

{
  string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");

  Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);

}
```

Regards

cmrhema

Comment: Redirect to the other page :)

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted will create the exact same URL, only with an `https:` perfix, as you are simply replacing `http:` with `https:`:

```
string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
```

If you want to redirect to another page, simply do that:

```
Response.Redirect("https://example.com/anotherPage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Switching Between HTTP and HTTPS Automatically: Version 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/WebPageSecurity_v2.aspx) with minor modifications very successfully. Takes a lot of the work out of it.